# ssh2_connect is undefined on debian

Tags: php, debian, libssh2

i have several server in debian 6.0.8 with php version at 5.3.28-1~dotdeb.0.

I have made an apt-get install libssh2-php on each.
When u made an php -v, i have openssl and ssh2 in the list on each.
I have already restarted apache after that.

But when i run a php script with ssh2_connect() call, it doesnt' work on 2 servers but it works on the other server.

I have the error : "call to undefined function ssh2_connect()."

I don't understand, debian version and php version are the same.
Can you help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: php -v only checks the command-line version of php. the SAPI (aka "in apache") version can/will use a different .ini file, and it probably isn't activated there. do a `phpinfo()` inside whatever script you're doing the ssh stuff in, just before you try to use ssh.

Comment: with phpinfo, i have the following verion of libSSH : libSSH Version  libssh2/1.2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In packaged distros like Debian and EL you have the "non-core" parts of PHP packaged separately. In Debian flavors you have to have the [php5-ssh2](https://packages.debian.org/sid/php5-ssh2) package installed.

> sudo apt-get install php5-ssh2

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

phpseclib has [a number of a advantages over libssh2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html). You can also use phpseclib to emulate the libssh2 functions, if you're so inclined. eg.

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer